# Highcharts 3.0 separate export buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I just updated my Highcharts version to 3.0, but now I see that there is one export-button, instead of the two separate buttons that used to be there (download - print).

Is it possible to make separate buttons again instead of the combined export-button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but maybe [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js) can help.
It's, in their own words, «a compatibility pack that brings the old look back to Highcharts 3.»
Also, the help topic on the export module [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) has links on how to implement your own buttons to call print and export, if you want.